# Shuffling elements in an Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, shuffle

I need a shuffle method to shuffle elements of an array which holds objects from another class. At the moment I wrote this code to test with integers first, but it seems to not working perfectly. Most of the elements are being duplicated.
Can someone please spot the mistake?
And also come up with a more efficient method for this.
I am not sure if I can use collections.shuffle because I have further use of my shuffled array later.

```
  public static void shuffle()
{
  int[] a = new int[52];
  int count = 0;
  int random = 0;
  while (count!=51){
    random = (int)(Math.random() * 52);
    for (int i=0; i <=count; i++){
      if (a[count] != b[random])
        result = true;
    }
    if (result){
      a[count] = b[random];
      count++; 
    }
    b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: *I am not sure if I can use collections.shuffle because I have further use of my shuffled array later.*. Could you please elaborate? Why couldn't you use your array later if you have called Collections.shuffle() before?

Comment: umm well, isnt that method for arrayList?

Comment: No. It's for `List`s. And you can create a `List` view on an array using `Arrays.asList()`.

Comment: I used the following:
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(b));

But it is printing the same exact array in order.

Comment: Arrays.asList(b) returns a list containing a single element, the array of ints b. Use an array of `Integer`: you can't create a `List<int>`.

Comment: Yeah. It worked. Thanks.
Will it also work with objects as elements of array?

Comment: Yes. shuffles changes the positions of elements in a list randomly, whatever the type of the elements is. Read the javadoc.

Comment: Thankyou.
If possible, could you spot error in my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random shuffling of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

First you should not define shuffle() in this way. I would treat b as a parameter and pass it into shuffle() instead of a static field (as your shuffle() is declared as static, your b is also static right? It looks strange to share b between all instances), and result is declared as a local variable.

This part

```
for (int i=0; i <=count; i++){
    if (a[count] != b[random])
        result = true;
    }
```

checks whether any one of a[0], a[1] until a[count] is not equal to b[random]. If yes, then assign b[random] to a[count] and increase count by 1. As a[] is not initialized, it is only an array of 0. (a[count] != b[random]) appears to be always true and hence result is true.

Then, for this part,

```
if (result){
    a[count] = b[random];
      count++; 
    }
```

say for example random=5, then at the first round of the while loop a[0]=b[5], count=1 (due to count++), and b becomes an array of b[5] and a series of 0. (Due to

```
b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
```

all other elements are replaced by 0.)

Edit: Here I provide a simple method, not thoroughly tested, but should work:

```
public static int[] shuffle(int[] array) {
    int[] a = new int[array.length];
    //convert int[] to ArrayList<Integer>
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i: array)
        list.add(i);
    //now shuffle:
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        int rand = (int)(Math.random()*list.size());
        a[i] = list.remove(rand);
    }
    return a;
}
```

The array returned is shuffled. Actually I can't say the method "shuffles" the array. It simply creates an empty array, and repeatedly selects an element randomly and put it at the front.

Edit2: This really "shuffles", and this is another approach: does not return a new array. It shuffles the array, 100 times.

```
public static void shuffle(int[] array) {
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        int r1 = (int)(Math.random()*array.length);
        int r2 = (int)(Math.random()*array.length);
        int tmp = array[r1];
        array[r1] = array[r2];
        array[r2] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Shuffle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] a = new Integer[52];
        for (Integer i=0;i<a.length;i++) a[i] = i+1;
        // Let's shuffle
        Random rd = new Random();
        for (Integer i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            Integer changeBy = rd.nextInt(a.length);
            Integer aux=a[i];
            a[i]=a[changeBy];
            a[changeBy] = aux;
        }
        // Now show the shuffled array
        for (Integer i=0;i < a.length; i++) System.out.print(a[i]+",");

    }

}
```

Hope this small algorithm helps you. As you can see from 2 different runs, it really shuffles your array:

11,1,24,13,28,15,25,48,5,22,12,32,29,42,34,7,33,31,47,18,51,40,8,17,41,20,6,36,21,45,27,52,38,10,30,14,23,19,43,4,50,46,44,3,49,37,35,2,9,26,16,39
3,10,37,26,41,15,28,52,6,24,20,43,33,21,51,32,25,40,50,8,7,5,4,35,13,16,49,17,29,47,12,14,36,39,45,30,2,42,23,38,31,19,27,46,34,11,18,1,22,48,9,44

Answer (score -1):

Why no you `HashSet` for shuffle?

Elements in `java.lang.HashSet` are shuffling by their hashcode.

```
public static void shuffle()
{
    int [] b; // you origin array
    Set<Integer> temp = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i : b) {
        temp.add(i);
    }
    Integer [] a = new Integer[b.length];
    a = temp.toArray(a); // new shuffle array

}
```

Comment: You don't really want to create a new `HashSet` everytime you want to shuffle, do you?

Comment: We havent studied HashSet yet so I can not use it.

Comment: Just because a HashSet maintains no order for its elements doesn't mean the order is random. That's a pretty big difference. HashSet doesn't shuffle anything.

Comment: @RohitJain create new `HashSet` for every shuffle is a bad practice. It wastes memory.

Comment: HashSet uses hashCode. Fine. That's right. But it uses them in a deterministic way. It doesn't shuffle its elements. Execute this: https://ideone.com/4tIZql, which "shuffles" a list of integers 10 times using your technique. Does that look shuffled randomly to you? Compare it to my technique: https://ideone.com/lXTSm4.

Comment: @JBNizet Integer.hashCode is qual to the primitive `int` value。

Comment: @lichengwu try it with whatever type you want. It will never be random. Also, a HashSet will remove duplicates.

Comment: @lichengwu: you get the exact same sequence of strings, from 90 to 10 in order, ten times in a row, and you stil think that's random? I wouldn't open a casino if I were you :)

Comment: It's random for every given array(not same). :)

Comment: OK. So your definition of "shuffling" is that, if I give you a deck of cards and ask you to shuffle it 10 times, you'll always give me the cards in the same order, because it's always the same deck of cards. Sorry, but that's not just what shuffling means. You're the only one on earth to have this definition of shuffling.